# Sinch Instant Messaging: User Not Found

Tags: sinch

I am integrating Sinch instant messenger into my app.  The purpose of this is to facilitate one-on-one communication between the user and app owner.  I have created the Sinch account and have the app keys.  When I try to send the message, I get an HTTP response : User not found.

Two questions:

1. I thought that since there will only ever be communication between the app owner and user, that I could get away without implementing Parse (or equivalent).  Is this true?  Could this be the cause of my issue?
2. How does Sinch create users?  I am having difficulty seeing in the documentation how that is handled and where the user data is stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. You dont need to use parse, but we dont proivde a login mechanism for users so you if you want login you need somekind of backend to handle you users,
2. WE create the users onhte fly when you start a client with that username, but again we trust that you authenticated them.